# Use common url prefix in all api methods?

Tags: android, retrofit2

android studio 3.6

in app/build.gradle:

```
def RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.6.0'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
```

In my Retrofit interface I has the next api methods

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*
import java.util.*

    @POST("/some_company_name/1.1.2/profile/change_password")
    fun changePassword(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

    @POST("/some_company_name/1.1.2/profile/register")
    fun register(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<JsonElement>

    @POST("/some_company_name/1.1.2/profile/update")
fun updateMe(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

As you can see all url has common prefix

```
/some_company_name/1.1.2/
```

Is it possible to not hardcode this prefeix in every methods.
But use some variable for this?
Smt like this:

```
@POST("${common_prefix}/profile/change_password")
fun changePassword(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

@POST("${common_prefix}/profile/register")
fun register(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<JsonElement>

@POST("${common_prefix}/profile/update")
fun updateMe(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a part of base url?

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA yes, "http://127.0.0.1:8081/some_company_name/1.1.2/profile/change_password " - it's part of base url

Comment: Then keep it with the Base URL. you don't have to clutter this class with that responsibility. Wherever you are providing the base url you will have the opportunity to change this dynamically as well

Answer (score 2):

Because "`some_company_name/1.1.2`" is used in every api method the best solution is to add  "`some_company_name/1.1.2`" to base url.
In **Retrofit** by removing the leading **/**, the URL then becomes relative and will combine with the path segments which are part of the base URL.

And remove leading **/** on my methods. The result is like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*
import java.util.*

    @POST("profile/change_password")
    fun changePassword(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

    @POST("profile/register")
    fun register(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<JsonElement>

    @POST("profile/update")
    fun updateMe(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

And now my base url is:

```
https://127.0.0.1/8001/some_company_name/1.1.2/
```

**Important**. Base url must finish by "**/**"

And now it's work fine.

Example of result:

```
https://127.0.0.1/8001/some_company_name/1.1.2/profile/register
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) for that.

For example:

```kotlin
class MyInterceptor : okhttp3.Interceptor {
    fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder = request.newBuilder()

        val httpUrl = request.url
        val httpUrlBuilder = httpUrl.newBuilder()

        val prefixIndex = httpUrl.pathSegments.indexOf("{my_prefix}")
        if (prefixIndex >= 0) {
            httpUrlBuilder.setPathSegment(prefixIndex, "your_common_value")
        }

        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.url(httpUrlBuilder.build()).build())
    }
}
```

Set it to your OkHttp client as follow:

```kotlin
OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(MyInterceptor())
    .build()
```

And update your Retrofit interface like this:

```kotlin
@POST("/{my_prefix}/1.1.2/profile/change_password")
fun changePassword(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using kotlin you can maybe do something like this:

```
@POST("{common_prefix}profile/change_password")
fun changePassword(@Path("common_prefix") commonPrefix: String = Constants.companyName, @Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

@POST("{common_prefix}profile/register")
fun register(@Path("common_prefix") commonPrefix: String = Constants.companyName, @Body body: JsonElement): Call<JsonElement>

@POST("${common_prefix}profile/update")
fun updateMe(@Path("common_prefix") commonPrefix: String = Constants.companyName, @Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

where `Constants.companyName` has this part of URL like this:

`val companyName = "/some_company_name/1.1.2/"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use a constant either in the same file privately or somewhere globally.

```
// at the end of the file outside of the class
private const val COMMON_PREFIX = "/some_company_name/1.1.2/"
```

**usage:**

```
@POST("$COMMON_PREFIX/profile/change_password")
fun changePassword(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

@POST("$COMMON_PREFIX/profile/register")
fun register(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<JsonElement>

@POST("$COMMON_PREFIX/profile/update")
fun updateMe(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```